# EF database as DLL gives an item with same key already exist

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I encounter an issue while using edmx file as dll in the aim to use it in other projects.

The problem is that database model works well when it is used within App_Code file but not when it is deployed as DLL!

Any idea on what is the problem?

Comment: Can I know why you downvoted me! I did many searches before posting my question.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your question is vague, supplies no specifics, code, or context within which to even being to guess what might be the problem.  For all we know, the problem is an infestation of small furry rodents.

Comment: I'm wondered where it is vague because there are three arguments mentioned {key already exist, App_Code & Library project} and I expected that any member with good knowledge about EF can know the source of it.

Comment: I find it ironic that you know what someone with knowledge you don't possess should be able to do.  In any event, you asked why the downvote.  I told you.  Since you refuse to accept my answer, good luck in getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests I arrived to fix it using the following:

- Recreate database model.
- Adding associations.
- Adding constraints.
- Generate database from model.